# How to interpret a mapping in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

So I am trying to find the image of the circle $(x-1)^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ under the mapping $F$ defined by 
$$(u,v) = F(x,y) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}(x+y), \frac{1}{2}(-x+y)\bigg)$$

Using computational methods I've concluded that the image is $(u-\frac{1}{2})^{2} + (v+\frac{1}{2})^{2} = \frac{1}{2}$, but I don't really understand *why* this is the case. I understand how to substitute lines, or endpoints into a mapping equation to see the subsequent image, but not the line of a circle. I guess, how would I do this without a visual interpretation?

Comment: Does it help to view the first coordinate of the image of $F$ as the average of $(x,y)$?

Comment: Calculate the image of the center of the circle under $F$, then pick any point on the original circle and calculate its image under $F$. You can now find the radius of the new circle, plus you already know the coordinates of its center which is enough to describe it via an equation. (although in general, not all mappings take circles to circles)

Comment: @MAM That's neat. But hmm yeah, I was wondering if there is a more computation approach with a change of variable or something to get the mapping equation.

Answer (score 0):

By your assumption we have $u=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)$ and $v=\frac{1}{2}(-x+y)$ so we get $u+v=x$ and $v-u=y$ for finding the image of mentioned circle we have$(u+v-1)^2+(v-u)^2=1$ which is again a circle.

Comment: In other words invert the function F, to express x, y in terms involving u,v and enter this into the sentence about x,y.